# Using P4CONFIG variables in p4 commands

Tags: perforce

Is it possible to use variables defined in P4CONFIG files in p4 commands? Let's say I want to define an alias for quickly seeing pending changelists in the current workspace. So something like:

```
p4 changes -s pending -c $P4CLIENT
```

I don't want to define P4CLIENT in my bashrc as I switch between different workspaces a lot. I much prefer it to come from the current P4CONFIG file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %clientName% info | p4 -x - changes -s pending -c
```

Note that you need a relatively current p4 client to use the undoc -F flag, which is described more here: http://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting

You could also script something around "p4 set P4CLIENT", which is a purely client-side query and therefore a bit faster, but you'll need to manipulate the output a bit to make it suitable as an argument to "p4 changes".

Comment: Thanks Sam. p4 does pick up my global options from my P4CONFIG file, the problem is the -c CLIENTNAME in "p4 changes" command is not part of the global options, i.e it has to be after the "changes"

Comment: My bad, I completely misunderstood what you were trying to do.  Lemme completely rewrite my answer to be correct.  :)